# Insertar "/" en una columna de SQL para darle formato de fecha

Tags: sql, date

Un cliente me envió su base de datos en las que van incluidas fechas, sin embargo vienen con un formato `YYYYMMDD`, y me gustaría crear una "query" donde pueda insertar en esa columna el delimitador `"/"` para que quede de esta manera `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Comment: ¿Cual base de datos usas? ¿Cual es el tipo de la columna en cuestion? Porque si la columna es de tipo fecha, como debería ser, entonces la columna no tiene formato. Si no es de tipo fecha, el diseño tiene un problema.

Comment: Es un base de datos .csv pero se envió todo como format varchar por lo que buscaba realizar ese ajuste, ya que si lo importo como date me sale error.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta de @sstan es por la base de datos donde vas a insertar estos datos. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Una base de datos almacena **datos** y aunque pudiese, no existe para almacenar **formatos o datos formateados**. Si almacenas un dato formateado no te sirve para nada más que para ese uso para el cual lo formateaste. Ni sirve para hacer cálculos con él, etc. El dato debe almacenarse tal cual es y cuando te toque presentar los datos entonces sí le das el formato que quieras: con / o con el nombre del mes o del día etc. En resumen: un dato YYYYMMDD y miles tipos de formato según las necesidades. Por eso existen funciones  para formatear los datos una vez los hemos sacado de la BD.

Comment: La mayoría de bases de datos reconocen ese formato como fecha y lo convierten en fecha al hacer la carga de la información a la tabla, siempre y cuando el campo que reciba ese dato sea Date.

Answer (score 1):

> me gustaría crear una "query" donde pueda insertar en esa columna el
>   delimitador "/" para que quede de esta manera YYYY/MM/DD

Lo que pretendes hacer es un **Error.**

**Una base de datos almacena datos** y aunque pudiese, **no existe para almacenar formatos o datos formateados**.

Si almacenas un dato formateado no te sirve para nada más que para ese uso para el cual lo formateaste. Tampoco sirve para hacer cálculos con él. Supongamos que luego quieres presentar esa fecha en otro formato, o que quieres calcular la diferencia entre dos columnas de tu tabla. Si la modificas añadiendo /, están simplemente echando a perder tus datos.

En la base de datos las columnas del [tipo fecha](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) deben almacenarse tal cual son y cuando te toque presentar su contenido entonces sí le das el formato que quieras, pero el dato estará guardado siempre así: YYYYMMDD. (A veces llevan la hora también, pero no es obligatorio).

Todos los manejadores de BD tienen instrucciones para presentar nuestros datos de la forma que deseemos. Mira, por el [ejemplo el caso de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Te dejo un ejemplo de un campo del tipo fecha, almacenado así YYYYMMDD y verás en el ejemplo tres formas de **presentar el mismo dato**. Pero si lo formateo en el orígen ya es imposible, se pierde esa flexibilidad.

---

[SQL Fiddle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tabla (
    `nombre` varchar(70),  `fecha_nacimiento` date  
);


INSERT INTO Tabla
    (`nombre`,  `fecha_nacimiento`)
VALUES
    ('Pedro','20000120'),
    ('Santiago','19990318'),
    ('Juan','19720822')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
   nombre,    
   DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nacimiento,'%Y%m%d') AS COMO_ES ,
   DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nacimiento,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DD_MM_YY ,
   DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nacimiento,'%Y/%m/%d') AS YYYY_MM_AA, 
   DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nacimiento,'%W %M %Y') AS UNO_LARGO 
FROM Tabla
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d05297/12/0)**:

```
|   nombre |  COMO_ES |   DD_MM_YY | YYYY_MM_AA |             UNO_LARGO |
|----------|----------|------------|------------|-----------------------|
|    Pedro | 20000120 | 20/01/2000 | 2000/01/20 | Thursday January 2000 |
| Santiago | 19990318 | 18/03/1999 | 1999/03/18 |   Thursday March 1999 |
|     Juan | 19720822 | 22/08/1972 | 1972/08/22 |   Tuesday August 1972 |
```